# tikz-qtree: curved lines & multiple parent nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree, linguistics

I am quite new to LaTeX, and I am stuck with a problem Google can't seem to help me with.
Basically, I need some hand holding in doing something that is more complicated than my skills can handle at this moment.

Basically, what I want to do is this:

[image]

I can currently get as far as the tree shown on the right side of the image above, using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [ [ \node(onset){r}; ] [ \node(mora1){e}; ].$\upmu$ [  ].\node(mora2){$\upmu$}; ].$\upsigma$
    \draw (mora1) -- (mora2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, that's the best I know how to do.
What I still need:

- how do I draw a curved line instead of a straight one?
- most importantly, how can I make two parent nodes share one child node, without it looking like crap as it does now?

I realize these may be noobish questions, but please understand that I did try Googling my problem and I just couldn't find the information I needed. The full TikZ manual is way over my head, and the `tikz-qtree` manual doesn't cover my case.

Thanks very much for any pointers you can give me.

Comment: Technically, if a child has two parents then that is no longer a tree.  It *might* be possible to do this using tree syntax, but is a solution using `tikz-qtree` essential or would you accept a more general one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Andrew notes, autosegmental representations of the sort you are drawing aren't really trees.  If you are likely to be drawing a lot of these, you might want to investigate the very powerful (but also very complicated) [`pst-asr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-asr) package.

In the meantime, here's a hybrid approach using `tikz-qtree` but positioning the segmental tier manually using TikZ's scope mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=.75cm}]
\Tree [.\node (syll) {$\upsigma$}; [.\node(m1) {$\upmu$}; ] [.\node (m2) {$\upmu$}; ] ]
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\node (e) {e};
\node (r) [left=1cm of e] {r};
\draw (e.north) -- (m1);
\draw (e.north) -- (m2);
\draw (r.north) edge[out=90,in=180] (syll.south);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]