# Crossed hierarchy

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees

I appreciate it if you let me know the most elegant way to draw a crossed hierarchy such as the followings:

```
    X
   /\
  Y  Z
  /\/\
 p q  t
```

q has two parents Y and Z.

Comment: You might find the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75413/86 useful here, as it also is concerned with "multiple parents" in a tree.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Another related recent question: [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a hack because it uses the fact that the distance between nodes doesn't change from level to level and so by default branches will overlap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {X} 
   child {
     node {Y}
     child {
        node {p}
     }
     child {
        node {q}
     }
   }
   child {
      node {Z}      
      child {
         node {\phantom{q}}      
      }
      child {
         node {t}      
      }
   }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

The edge from Z to q is not really to the q but to an invisible q that sits on top of the first q.

A better way to do it is to name the nodes and draw the extra edge after the tree.  This way if the q node moves the extra edge will still point to it.  You can create a `missing` child node to keep the spacing as if there were an actual first child.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm},
   level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm}
]
\node {X} 
   child {
     node {Y}
     child {
        node {p}
     }
     child {
        node (q) {q}
     }
   }
   child {
      node (Z) {Z}      
      child[missing] {
         node {q}
      }
      child {
         node {t}      
      }
   }
;
\draw (Z) -- (q);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: @MasoodGhayoomi If this really helped you, apart from upvoting it, please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark. This marks your problem as solved. :)