# Associating two children to one parent in Forest

Tags: forest

I am trying to draw a nice multi-dominance. I find the gap between the two lines above "V" is ugly. Is there any way to move the lower end of the line in red square so that the two lines meet at one point right north of "V"?

[image]Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} where n children=0{tier=CV}{}
    [\sg
    [C, tier=CV]
    [\mo[, tier=CV, no edge][V, name=V, tier=CV]]
    [\mo, name=mo[, no edge, tier=CV]]]
    \draw (mo)--(V);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Here's a `forest` solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146183/146210#146210). Instead of `forest`, you can also try other methods of drawing such graphs. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114109/) for example. If you don't mind using pstricks (I do), you can try the [`pst-asr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-asr) package. [This uses `tikz-qtree`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75413/). You can also directly use the (layered) [graph syntax in TikZ](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=258).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{forest} where n children=0{tier=CV}{s sep+=-.5em}
    [\sg
    [C, tier=CV]
    [,phantom]
    [\mo, name=mo1[, tier=CV, no edge]]
    [,phantom[V, name=V, tier=CV]]
    [\mo, name=mo2[, no edge, tier=CV]]]
    \draw (mo1.south)--(V.north);
    \draw (mo2.south)--(V.north);
\end{forest}
```

I think this works.