# Uniting tree branches in the forest package

Tags: beamer, forest

I have the following forest in Beamer:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    %edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep'+=10pt,
    fork sep'=10pt,
  },
  forked edges,
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
  }{},
  [Degredation Modeling
    [Mechanical\\Models]
    [Statistical\\Models
     [Deterministic\\Models]
     [Probabilistic\\Models
     [Continuous\\Distributions]
     [Bayesian\\Models]
     ]
     [Stochastic\\Models
      [Markov Models]
      [Poisson and \\Other Processes]
      ]
     ]
    [Mechanical-Statistical \\Models]
    [Artificial Intelligence\\Models ]
      ]
\end{forest}  
}
```

What I want to do is, I want to combine the last four leaves in the sublayers of Probabilistic and Stochastic Models, and write the common advantages and disadvantages of the models. How can I do this reverse branching as given below? (It doesn't have to be straight arrows or lines, anything indicating these four nodes also work)
[image]

Comment: [Associating two children to one parent in Forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238625/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Could you please also make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

One possibilities are giving names to end nodes (see MWE below) and draw extra node below them and connect this node with named ones.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % <--------


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    forked edge,
    s sep'=2pt,
    l sep'=8pt,
    fork sep'=7pt,
    },
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
            }{},
[Degredation Modeling
    [Mechanical\\Models]
    [Statistical\\Models
        [Deterministic\\Models]
        [Probabilistic\\Models
            [Continuous\\Distributions, name=a] % <---
            [Bayesian\\Models, name=b] % <---
        ]
         [Stochastic\\Models
            [Markov\\ Models, name=c] % <---
            [Poisson and \\Other Processes, name=d] % <---
         ]
    ]
    [Mechanical-Statistical \\Models]
    [Artificial Intelligence\\Models]
]
\foreach \i in {a,...,d}    % <---------
\draw[semithick]  
    (\i) -- ($(a)!0.5!(d) + (0,-1.5)$) 
    node[below, align=center] {They are acurate,\\
                               but require data, etc} ; 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** MWE is now adopted to `beamer` document class.-